# Binary and multi-class classification code change

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, multiclass-classification

I am using almost similar code that I found here...

https://towardsdatascience.com/classify-butterfly-images-with-deep-learning-in-keras-b3101fe0f98

The example is related to binary classification. The data that I am testing with is calling for multi-class classification. I guess I need to change activation and loss function. Can I use the same code found here if I have more than 2 types?

https://github.com/bertcarremans/Vlindervinder/blob/master/model/CNN.ipynb

---

update:
I have one more question. Is augmentation necessary if I have enough data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy`:

```py
cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer='rmsprop',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

If your labels are not one-hot encoded modify these lines:

```py
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',
    target_size=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/validation',
    target_size=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

Comment: Getting an error wth that https://github.com/shantanuo/pandas_examples/blob/master/tensorflow/simages_train.ipynb

Comment: # ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_4 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)

Comment: Change output layer from `cnn.add(Dense(1))` to `cnn.add(Dense(4))`

Answer (score 2):

No, that is multi-label classification. You said multi-class. Here is a summary for you:

- **Binary:** You have *single* output of 0 or 1. You use something like `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` in the final layer and `binary_cross_entropy` as loss function.
- **Multi-label:** You have *multiple* outputs of 0s or 1s; `Dense(num_labels, activation='sigmoid')` and again `binary_cross_entropy`. In this case, an example can belong to *multiple labels at the same time*.
- **Multi-class:** Example belongs to *1 out of N classes*, they are mutually exclusive. You use `Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')` with `softmax_crossentropy`.